# Insert data into MySql DB

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm creating a class and I have a function with which I want to insert some data into an table from some inputs. It works if I check the table but I keep getting the error "number of arguments in prepare doesn't match the no of arg in bind_result". Also I don't know if my method is correct ..

```
private function insertData($foldName,$foldClass,$foldLink) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO folders (folder_name,folder_class,folder_link) VALUES ('$foldName','$foldClass','$foldLink')";

    if($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($foldName,$foldClass,$foldLink);
        $stmt->close();
        $error = false;
        $message['error'] = false;
        $message['message'] = "Data Successfuly Inserted";
        return json_encode($message);
    }
        else {
            $error = true;
            $message['error'] = true;
            $message['message'] = "Data Failed To Insert";
            return json_encode($message);
        }

}
```

Comment: An insert statement doesn't return a result set, so there is actually nothing to bind to, I would say; just remove the `$stmt->bind_result...` line

Comment: I take it this is a question about `mysqli`?

Comment: it is related to mysqli yes, and I just removed the bind_result(). Let me test it and see what's happening now ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `bind_result` at all as you are inserting data and not selecting any.

But you should use the core features of your prepared statement. That is: safely passing the variables to the statement object instead of inserting their "raw" values into the SQL string:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO folders (folder_name,folder_class,folder_link) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $foldName, $foldClass, $foldLink);
$stmt->execute();
```

(I have not tested it.)

Comment: I just did, and it worked :) And yes, I wanted to have that if( ...prepare...) so I can see if there was an error during the process ... Also now the index is 5, I mean the folder_id which I set it to Auto Increment int(11), could I reset it somehow so it starts with one ?

Comment: @Roland I am glad that it works. I skipped the `if`-statement just because of simplicity in my example. For sure, you should stay with your `if`-statement. Regarding the `auto_increment`-column: You could drop the column `folder_id` and directly re-add it, or execute a MySQL statement like this one: `ALTER TABLE folders AUTO_INCREMENT=1`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did it from phpmyadmin. I'm working on local server with XAMPP. And sometimes I see OVERHEAD 80 and I click to optimize it, but why is that showing ?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the first example on this manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are emptying the table's data as a whole, use the `truncate` query:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `table_name`
```

This would reset the `auto_increment` to 1, but if you don't want to empty the whole table you can `alter` it instead:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` auto_increment = 1
```

Comment: well, I'm emptying it to prepare it for populating it with an multidimensional array. And it has to be empty before I do that. I have an multidimensional array `$array = array( array('Name'=>'Somename','Class'=>'Someclass','Link'=>'Somelink'), array(the same as the other one));` and I want to loop through it and take the second level arrays and store them in the db, the same db I have above in the question. I was thinking like this : http://snippi.com/s/m7cl7gr . Could that work ?

Comment: I tested that and it works fine. Thanks for the tip about truncate :)