# Insert Into query and expecting more than one result?

Tags: php, sql, insert, mysqli

I have a mysqli function that is inserting a row into a table. I'm getting back the error

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of 
fields in prepared statement
```

This is odd to me since I thought insert nto returns true or false. Here is the function that is using the sql statement.

```
function add_project_deadline ($mysqli, $project_id, $deadline) {


if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `project_deadline` (project_id, deadline) 
    VALUES (?, ?)")){
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $project_id, $deadline);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($return);
    $stmt->close();
    return $return;
} else {return false;}  

}
```

My question is why am I getting this bind_result error and how do I fix it.

Comment: Start by *reading the error/warning message message*: -1 to help encourage this process. Now, *why* might it say that? And what change(s) might "fix" it?

Comment: I did read the error message. I always thought that if it returns true, then there will be a result that you can bind to a variable. Unless you can't which if that is the case how would I know the query passed? If I'm wrong on that, then am I to assume that an insert into query returns multiple results? I really don't know. I just want enlightenment and an explanation on what insert into returns on a true or false and how can I return that value when a query is with mysqli.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501651/insert-data-into-mysql-db

Comment: And as for whether your insert works or not, you can check the return value on your [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are executing an `INSERT` query which doesn't have any results, you don't need or use `bind_result` for fetching data.  `bind_result` is for binding to columns used in a SELECT statement.

`mysqli_stmt::execute()` returns `true` on success or `false` on failure so simply assign the value of that to your `$return` variable.

If `execute()` returns false, the `INSERT` statement failed for some reason.  If it returns `true`, the `INSERT` was successful and you can determine the number of rows inserted by looking at the `mysqli_stmt::$affected_rows` property of your statement object.

That's why you're getting that error, hope it helps.  You can find most of this information on the manual page for [`mysqli_stmt::execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).